# Como filtrar por rango de hora en un campo Datetime SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola quisiera como filtrar los datos en un campo datetime, es decir quiero selecionar los datos que esten entre cierta hora

```
select *From dbo.att_punches
where punch_time=11:45 and 13:20
```

es algo asi lo que deseo hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el campo es de tipo `time`, puedes filtrar directamente sobre él:

```
select *
  from dbo.att_punches
 where punch_time between '11:45:00' and '13:20:00'
```

SQL Server hará automáticamente la conversión de tipo cadena a tipo time para aplicar el filtro, o puedes hacerla explícitamente:

```
select *
  from dbo.att_punches
 where punch_time between cast('11:45:00' as time) and cast('13:20:00' as time)
```

Ahra, si tienes un campo tipo `datetime` con información de fechas y horas y quieres obtener los registros de ciertas horas independientemente de la fecha, puedes usar la técnica de convertir horas y minutos a un número entero de la forma `hhmm` para que se puedan comparar. Para lograrlo multiplicas las horas por 100 y le sumas los minutos, por ejemplo:

```
select *
  from dbo.att_punches
 where hour(punch_time) * 100 + minute(punch_time) between 1145 and 1320
```

Toma en cuenta que esto te devolverá incluso los registros que hayan ocurrido hasta el final del minuto 13:20, es decir hasta las 13:20:59.999.

Si quieres filtrar hasta las 13:20:00.000 deberás incluir segundos y milisegundos en el filtro, o bien filtrar hasta las 13:59:59.999 cambiando el límite superior a 1359.

He utilizado este truco por años, pues es efectivo para comparar rangos de fechas y horas, aunque su rendimiento no es el mejor, pues el motor no puede valerse de índices para realizar el filtrado, por lo que implica regularmente escaneos de tablas completas que debes considerar si tienen muchos registros o un gran volumen de estas consultas.

En estos casos, será mejor tener un campo de tipo time, que puede ser calculado o derivado de la fecha, indexar y filtrar directamente sobre dicho campo.

Comment: Eres un genio gracias

Comment: Hombre, gracias, yo lo creo, pero no está bien que yo lo diga. :)